# Qt Stream Audio Over TCP Socket In Realtime

Tags: qt, sockets, audio, stream

I'm trying to figure out how to stream audio in realtime over TCP sockets in Qt.  What I'm using is a `QAudioInput` on the client and `QAudioOutput` on the server. Both are using the following format:

```
QAudioFormat format;
format.setChannelCount(1);
format.setSampleRate(8000);
format.setSampleSize(8);
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);
```

I have a simple socket server setup already and managed to stream the audio from the client to the server using:

```
//client
QAudioInput *audio = new QAudioInput(format, this);
audio->setBufferSize(1024);
audio->start(socket);


//server
QAudioOutput *audio = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
audio->setBufferSize(1024);
```

Then on the server I'm receiving the data and appending it to a `QByteArray`

On the server, I create a `QBuffer` and give it the `QByteArray` once the client closes, and then play it like this:

```
QByteArray *data = new QByteArray();

while(1)
{
    if(socket->waitForReadyRead(30000))
        data->append(socket->readAll());
    else
        break;
}

QBuffer *buffer = new QBuffer(data);
QEventLoop *loop = new QEventLoop(this);
buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
audio->start(buffer);

loop->exec();
```

This will play the entire stream AFTER the client closes. What I'm looking for is to modify the server to play it in realtime, but I can't figure out how. I've gotten close to realtime but it had loud clicks between packets and was delayed several seconds.

I've tried playing the stream like how I used to send it:

```
audio->start(socket);
```

but this doesn't do anything. Maybe if I use `QDataStream` instead of directly using the sockets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to solve that problem I simply increased the `setBufferSize` from your 1024 to a higher value, for example i've used 8192, that way you give the chance to the devices read more data at a time, and I was able to stream audio over my wireless network.

My class design is a little bit different than yours, I have different classes for sockets and audio, and you can see it [here](https://github.com/antonypro/AudioStreaming/).

Comment: You couldn't post your project could you? I set mine up to 8192 but I'm not getting anything...

Comment: I've added a link to a sample project